# Editing a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe called _data which looks like this:

```
frame   id   x1     y1  x2  y2  score class visibility
  1     1   1363    569 103 241  1      1   0.86014
  2     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  3     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  4     5   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  5     5   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  6     5   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  7     6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  8     6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  9     7   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  10    7   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
                         .
                         .
                         .
```

There are 108003 rows and 141 unique IDs in the dataframe. An ID represents a specific object and the ID is repeated as long as that frame has that object. In other words, my data has 141 different objects and 108003 frames. I wrote a code to identify frames that have the same objects but is labelled with a different ID. This is saved in another dataframe called _data_to_merge which looks like this.

```
indexID  matchID    
   4        5
   6        7
   8        9
   12       13
   18       19
   20       21
       .
       .
       .
```

The second dataframe shows which indexes has been wrongly classified as a different object. The 'indexID' in _data_to_merge is the same as 'id' in _data.

Taking the first line in _data_to_merge as an example, it says that index 4 and 5 is the same. Therefore, I need to change the 'id' values of all the 'id' 5 in _data to 4. This is an example of what the final table should look like after changing all the 'id'.

_datanew:

```
frame   id   x1     y1  x2  y2  score class visibility
  1     1   1363    569 103 241  1      1   0.86014
  2     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  3     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  4     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  5     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  6     4   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  7     6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  8     6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  9     6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
  10    6   1362    568 103 241  1      1   0.86173
                         .
                         .
                         .
```

All the rows with 'id' 5 has been changed to 4 and all the rows of 'id' 7 has been changed to 6. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = _data_to_merge.set_index('matchID')['indexID']
_data['id'] = _data['id'].map(s).combine_first(_data['id']).astype(int)
print (_data)
   frame  id    x1   y1   x2   y2  score  class  visibility
0      1   1  1363  569  103  241      1      1     0.86014
1      2   4  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
2      3   4  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
3      4   4  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
4      5   4  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
5      6   4  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
6      7   6  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
7      8   6  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
8      9   6  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
9     10   6  1362  568  103  241      1      1     0.86173
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. What is new_id?

Comment: @RuvenGuna - it is new matched `ID` from df2 to df1. Or need something else?

Comment: I am actually looking to edit the 'id' in _data and not to add a new column.

Comment: I think I did not explain my issue clearly. I have editted my question to better explain my problem.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - So need change `_data_to_merge.set_index('indexID')['matchID']` to `s = _data_to_merge.set_index('matchID')['indexID']` ?

Comment: I editted the code and it does not seem to work for all the values. All matched indexes of 140 and above were removed but their frame numbers were changed. The frame number should actually be the same and the only thing that changes should be the 'id' in df1.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - If values was removed, are you sure matched? E.g. in sample data are missing `1,2,3` values in `_data_to_merge`, so for this data are created `NaN`s.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. The 'id' values should be replaced by the correct value. For example, 5 should be replaced by 4. There should not be any missing values.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - OK, so this is my first solution. It not working?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is till not working. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @RuvenGuna - Sorry, second row of code was necessary change too. Now solution working. Check edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
id_to_replace = dict(_data_to_merge[['index_id', 'match_id']].values)
_data['id'] = _data[['id'].map(id_to_replace)
```

Comment: Hi, I have editted my question to better explain my problem. I tried running your code but when I run the program, it says that some other lines, not the lines you gave me, in my code has invalid syntax and when I run it without your code, the program is able to run. Could there be a compatibility issue as I am using python 2.

Comment: I wonder what exactly is the error you get? I don't readily see anything that could cause compatibility issue...

Comment: I am also quite confused as to why it does that. This is an example of an error: 
` File "main.py", line 152
    _data.to_csv("data.csv", sep=',')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: This is not very helpful. You would have to post the whole file or isolate the lines that still manifest the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not too sure how I can post a clearer explanation of the error in the comments section because of the limited formatting but basically the error points at the . in data.to_csv and saying that it has invalid syntax. And when I comment that line out, it will point at a : in else: also saying that it is a syntax error. However, when I remove the lines of code that you suggested to me, the program is able to run without those syntax errors. I hope this explains it better.

Comment: Add it to the question or create a new one pertaining to the exact error and link it in the comment.